# Uploading to Arduino Nano error. Nano Clone CH340

Tags: arduino, nano

Arduino: 1.8.15 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

Sketch uses 5262 bytes (17%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.

Global variables use 466 bytes (22%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1582 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

```
avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0xfc



avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x90



avrdude: arduino_read_sig_bytes(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x10, resp=0xfc

avrdude: error reading signature data for part "ATmega328P", rc=-3

avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-3

avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-3
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Please Help. I want to update the code on it. Last time I uploaded a year ago

Comment: Try [arduino.se].

Answer (score 0):

Try with board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P".

No *Old Bootloader*.